# how to keep page body from scrolling under header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, header, scroll, position

I have the following "layout.cshtml" file in an MVC 5 project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

</head>

<body style="background-image: url('/Content/images/background.png')">
<div id="master" style="padding: 20px; width: 100%; position: fixed; height: 75px; z-index: 9999;">
    bunch of stuff removed for clarity
</div>

    @RenderBody()

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

The "master" div contains a toolbar that is populated via JS and positioned at the top of the page, where it remains on top of everything and ignores scrolling of the page so that it's always visible.  That part seems to work fine.

The problem is that the rest of my page (that which is filled in via the @RenderBody() call) will scroll underneath the toolbar.  I would like to keep the top of that section from going any higher than the bottom of the toolbar.  I tried putting the @RenderBody() within its own div, and trying various "positions" (fixed, relative, absolute).  I even tried a div around that div, with various combinations of "positions" for both.  I either get a body that won't scroll at all, or one that scrolls underneath the toolbar.

Is there any way to do what I'm looking to do?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the div with id='master' has the position style set to fixed, it will be displayed in a fixed position relative to the browser window. In order to move the content that it displayed "below" it, you should set

```
style="margin-top:75px"
```

to the element/container that follows this div. This will push it down from behind the master div so that it is not overlapped.

Example:

```
<div style="margin-top:75px">
    @RenderBody()

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</div>
```

SECOND OPTION: You may also want to consider setting

```
position:relative
```

instead of

```
position:absolute
```

UPDATE (see comment below):

Try setting the position of the sub-header (script section) div to fixed, just like the main header section, then set the 'top' property to 75px. This will lock it to the base of the main header:

```
<div style="position:fixed; top:75px;">
    @RenderBody()

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</div>
```

UPDATE 2:
Set this style on both the header and the body. First this will hide content that would normally be visible behind the header buttons. Second, this will lock the backgrounds of both containers together so scrolling won't cause a seam to appear between them. This gives the effect of the central content disappearing when it reaches the lower edge of the header.

```
background: url("/Content/images/background.png") repeat fixed 0% 0% transparent;
```

Comment: I thought for sure this would work, as it makes perfect sense and is one of the few things I didn't think to try.  Sadly, it does not.  I have tried several combinations of setting margins and positions on either or both divs (I tried adding one around @RenderBody() as well), but none of them worked as I want it to.  The body of the page continues to scroll underneath the toolbar.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your original question. See my update above.

Comment: I'm afraid this still doesn't quite do it.  If I set the second div to "fixed", then I get no scroll on that section, so whatever doesn't fit in the browser window can't be seen or gotten to.  If I use "relative" or "absolute", then it still scrolls underneath the toolbar above.

Comment: I think I am having trouble understanding your requirements. Could you provide me with a link to an example of the page you are working on, so that I can see what you are describing? A link to another website with a similar feature could also provide clarity.

Comment: If you go to http://www.magicsoftsolutions.com/Account/Index you can see what I mean.  You might have to adjust your browser to make sure the scrolling is necessary, but you'll see that the page will scroll underneath the toolbar at the top.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, the background of your header is transparent, so as the content moves behind the fixed header it remains visible. To prevent this from happening, you would need a background on the header. Try changing the header and body css to use the background I describe above.

Comment: I had to play around with this just a bit (which is probably because I either misunderstood what you were saying or because I hadn't been totally clear on what my page code looked like to begin with).

I actually had to set the body style as you directed (which was already set to that background, minus the extra properties), and the style of the div around the toolbar.  Then I just kept the div around the @RenderBody() to style="top: 75px; position: relative;" as you had suggested before.

Now it does exactly what I was hoping for.  Thanks so much.  :)